# How do I skew the text generated by fillText() for the canvas tag in HTML5?

Tags: html, canvas

How do I skew the text generated by fillText() for the canvas tag in HTML5?

Would it be done the same way as MozTransform, webkitTransform, oTransform, transform, etc.?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a statement like

```
context.setTransform (1, -0.2, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

See the [spec for canvas transformations](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#transformations).

So where you'd use a CSS line like

```
-moz-transform:  matrix(a, c, b, d, tx, ty)
```

you can use the Javascript

```
context.setTransform (a, c, b, d, tx, ty);
```

An example of drawing text would be

```
context.font = '20px arial,sans-serif' ;
context.fillStyle = 'black' ;
context.setTransform (1, -0.2, 0, 1, 0, 0);
context.fillText ('your text', 10, 10) ;
context.setTransform (1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

Note the final `setTransform`, which sets the transform back to the identity.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, I was trying context.style.MozTransform = "skewx(45deg)"; and context.MozTransform = "skewx(45deg)"; (as well as the WebKit and Presto versions of that, but those weren't working with canvas.